# How to create a model in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm watching the old flutter course because I couldn't really find a new one. But since flutter is constantly updated, it becomes a little more challenging as soon as you learn from the old courses.

Here is my questions:

1. Is fromObject still here or just changed to fromJson?
2. Do you have a model sample?
3. How can I do my _id is unique?(Usin sql etc.)

I'm trying something like this but I'm getting an error in 'Product.fromObject'.

````
class Product {
  int _id;
  String _name;
  String _description;
  double _price;

  Product(this._id, this._name, this._description, this._price);
  Product.withId(this._id, this._name, this._description, this._price);

  int get id => _id;
  String get name => _name;
  String get description => _description;
  double get price => _price;

  set name(String value) {
    if (value.length >= 2) {
      _name = value;
    }
  }

  set description(String value) {
    if (value.length >= 10) {
      _description = value;
    }
  }

  set price(double value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      _price = value;
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    var map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map["name"] = _name;
    map["description"] = _description;
    map["price"] = _price;
    map["id"] = _id;

    return map;
  }

  Product.fromObject(dynamic o) {
    _id = o["id"];
    _name = o["name"];
    _description = o["description"];
    _price = o["price"];
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now It's changed to fromJson.

```
class Post{
  int userid;
  int id;
  String title;
  String body;

  Post({userid, id, title, body});

  Post fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    Post post = Post();
    post.userid = json["userId"];
    post.id = json['id'];
    post.title = json['title'];
    post.body = json['body'];
    return post;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson(Post post){
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      "userId": post.userid,
      "id": post.id,
      "title": post.title,
      "body": post.body
    };
    return data;
  }

}
```

I have attached a sample model class for your reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can read about json serialization here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json

The correct method to parse from json is a factory method that is called fromJson and takes a map.

Comment: Not exactly answering my questions but thanks.